# How do I structure the following formula correctly?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In worksheet 2, I want to use a value from a certain cell in worksheet 1, if
the text in a cell in worksheet 2 contains a specific word.  How do I do
that?

IF (text in Worksheet 2, Cell C5 contains “VVV”, enter the value from
Worksheet 1, Cell D16) OR IF (text in Worksheet 2, Cell C5 contains
“WWW”, enter the value from Worksheet 1, Cell G16) OR IF (text in
Worksheet 2, Cell C5 contains “XXX”, enter the value from Worksheet 1,
Cell J16) OR IF (text in Worksheet 2, Cell C5 contains “YYY”, enter the
value from Worksheet 1, Cell M16) OR IF (text in Worksheet 2, Cell C5
contains “ZZZ”, enter the value from Worksheet 1, Cell P16)

To test for the first value, I used this formula, which works:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Multi",C5)),'Pricing Calculator'!D16)
```

However, when I add a 2nd value, the formula does not work:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Multi",C6)),'Pricing Calculator'!D16)OR IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Vegaflor",C6)),'Pricing Calculator'!G16)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OR has a different meaning.  That's used to include multiple possible conditions to produce the same result.  The structure is `OR(condition1, condition2,...)`.  If any one or more component conditions are true, the OR returns TRUE or 1.  You want different results for different conditions.  See Scott Craner's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to nest the IFS not use OR:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Multi",C5)),'Pricing Calculator'!D16,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Vegaflor",C5)),'Pricing Calculator'!G16,...))
```

Continue on adding nested ifs in the `...` spot.

we can also simplify the formula by using INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX('Pricing Calculator'!16:16,,aggregate(15,7,((ROW(1:5)-1)*3+4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"VVV","WWW","XXX","YYY","ZZZ"},C5))),1))
```

Replace the `"VVV","WWW","XXX","YYY","ZZZ"` with your desired text to find.

To deal with when C5 is none:

Nested IF, the last if end with `'Pricing Calculator'!P16,"")`

With the shorter version just wrap in IFERROR

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Pricing Calculator'!16:16,,aggregate(15,7,((ROW(1:5)-1)*3+4)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"VVV","WWW","XXX","YYY","ZZZ"},C5))),1)),"")
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you, Scott!  If a cell in column C is blank and f I want the formula cell not to display anything or display a 0 instead of FALSE, what should I enter at the end of the formula?

Comment: @Dave see edit.

Comment: This situation might be a good candidate for the newer IFS function.

Comment: @Jeeped thought about that but one will still be typing out all the ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) and the various `'Pricing Calculator'!@16`, which is too much typing when a simple, fairly limited array formula will do it with a lot less typing.